# function for clearing a table on reset

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Team, I have created code to print a 9X9 matrix using user's input without refreshing the page. Now I want to reset (Clear) the table or field of that 9X9 matrix without refreshing the page.

Please help me out and tell me some suggestions on ajax or other codes.

Comment: Someone is going to certainly ask you to show what you've tried, and that someone is apparently me.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: 9x9 matrix … suggestions on ajax … it's very difficult to work out what you're asking. Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/):

`$('#myFormId').resetForm();`